# Browse through json array in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have this array :

```
{"endroits":[{"id":"8","pseudo":"khaled","password":"android321"},
             {"id":"9","pseudo":"oussama","password":"laidi"},
             {"id":"11","pseudo":"Moulay","password":"fitna"},
             {"id":"13","pseudo":"admin","password":"admin"},
             {"id":"14","pseudo":"laidi","password":"l3ide"},
             {"id":"15","pseudo":"tarabet","password":"tarabet"}]}
```

I want to browse and get the attribute (id, pseudo, password). How can I do that?

Comment: Please include some code to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as below

```
var obj = {"endroits":[{"id":"8","pseudo":"khaled","password":"android321"},{"id":"9","pseudo":"oussama","password":"laidi"},{"id":"11","pseudo":"Moulay","password":"fitna"},{"id":"13","pseudo":"admin","password":"admin"},{"id":"14","pseudo":"laidi","password":"l3ide"},{"id":"15","pseudo":"tarabet","password":"tarabet"}] };

alert( obj.endroits[0].id );
alert( obj.endroits[0].pseudo );
```

EDIT(For all)

```
for (elem in obj.endroits) {
   console.log(obj.endroits[elem].id);
   console.log(obj.endroits[elem].pseudo);
   console.log(obj.endroits[elem].password);
}
```

OR

```
for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
{
    alert( obj.endroits[i].id );
    alert( obj.endroits[i].pseudo );
}
```

Comment: Loop through that obj and you get all array

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Array.prototype.forEach()`

```js
var data = {
  "endroits": [{
    "id": "8",
    "pseudo": "khaled",
    "password": "android321"
  }, {
    "id": "9",
    "pseudo": "oussama",
    "password": "laidi"
  }, {
    "id": "11",
    "pseudo": "Moulay",
    "password": "fitna"
  }, {
    "id": "13",
    "pseudo": "admin",
    "password": "admin"
  }, {
    "id": "14",
    "pseudo": "laidi",
    "password": "l3ide"
  }, {
    "id": "15",
    "pseudo": "tarabet",
    "password": "tarabet"
  }]
}

data.endroits.forEach(function(val) {
  console.log(val.id, val.pseudo, val.password)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plunker using jQuery.each

https://plnkr.co/edit/L8NOAJZkWQTDqXVIcQQ9

```
var obj = {
    "endroits": [{
        "id": "8",
        "pseudo": "khaled",
        "password": "android321"
    }, {
        "id": "9",
        "pseudo": "oussama",
        "password": "laidi"
    }, {
        "id": "11",
        "pseudo": "Moulay",
        "password": "fitna"
    }, {
        "id": "13",
        "pseudo": "admin",
        "password": "admin"
    }, {
        "id": "14",
        "pseudo": "laidi",
        "password": "l3ide"
    }, {
        "id": "15",
        "pseudo": "tarabet",
        "password": "tarabet"
    }]
};



document.write(obj["endroits"][0].pseudo);
document.write("<br>");
document.write(obj["endroits"][1].pseudo);
document.write("<br><br>");

document.write("jQuery Foreach:<br>");
jQuery.each(obj["endroits"], function(index, value) {
  document.write(value.pseudo)
  document.write("<br>");
})
```